# JMeter Thread Groups - Is it possible to make the same instance of one behave as a time based or an iteration based element dynamically at runtime?

Tags: jmeter

I am creating a JMeter Test Harness that will be run from Jenkins using "Build with Parameters' to set runtime parameters that are passed into JMeter as Properties using -J attributes.

End users will be given the choice of running tests either based on the number of iterations or a period of time.

I can easily interrogate a passed in property value to determine if an 'iteration' or 'time' based test type and in order to try this I have added variables (which may or may not be have values depending) for ALL of the Thread Group 'Thread Properties' fields as can be seen below. Each variable will have a value of either 0 or 1+ depending upon the Jenkins parameters passed in at runtime.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuPJa.jpg)

As I do not want to create 2 Thread Groups (one for iteration based, and the other time based) then use logic controllers or similar to control what way to test, is there a dynamic way to switch the Thread Group 'Thread Properties" behaviour at run time using the singular Thread Group?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HnBJ.jpg)
Any help in making 1 thing do 2 things in my little world of JMeter will be greatly appreciate!!

Answer (score 0):

Not really, with "vanilla" JMeter you can:

1. Set number of iterations to `-1` for "duration" based test
2. Set duration to a very long value (a couple of years) for the "iteration" based test

Other options are in:

1. JMeter [.jmx scripts](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JmxTestPlan) are basically [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) files and XML is a subset of text so you can use a text editor like [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) to substitute values directly in the .jmx file
2. [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/) automation framework has a nice feature of [modifying an existing JMeter test](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#Modifications-for-Existing-Scripts) before launching, it allows overriding absolutely any property of absolutely any element.

Comment: Hi Dmitri,

Thanks for answering!

I'd already implemented a revised approach adopting similar to your answer which works, and whilst Taurus seems like an easier option, it is not one from the project's point of view.

I regularly edit the .jmx in Intellij as it's a lot quicker for mass changes that the JMeter GUI route is, but I'd never considered passing runtime variables to the JMX itself rather than say a Thread Group inside one of them! 

I now have Iteration 2 of the Test Harness mapped out! I'll post back in the future with hopefully success!

Thank you for the sound advice!